# How can i create a listviewbuilder like that

Tags: flutter, dart

i will make an app. The app is shows income day by day. I will sort them and i need to show sum of each day's total income.

I draw it to paint.  You can see on attached.

In my codes, i got timestamps and values of money. Need some help.

This is my desire.

[image: 1]

Comment: You can return Column from itemBuilder containing those children.

Comment: The problem is i can't seperate dates and can't calculate total depending the spesific day

Comment: Un plugin de ce type pourrait pas t'aider
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header

Comment: it looking usefull widget but my problem is, how can i seperate dates from timestamp in listbuilder. My problem is not related with UI design, the problem is about ; I want to separate the dates day by day. But i can't.